# "Invalid image type" without reason

Tags: support

I tried to add some details to my profile page, such as location and birthday.
I did not try to change my profile picture, because I've a good one.

However, after clicking the Save Profile button, only outcome is red text

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> ```
> Invalid image type
> ```

and location, birthday & about me fields remains unchanged.

Comment: Is your image bigger than 2 MiB? Which is your file extension?

Comment: My profile image is added about 6 months ago (when I created my account). Some days ago I tried add details to profile, not change profile image. So I cannot answer your question.

It is possible that my profile image is originally uploaded in png format, but unfortunately I cannot know sure.

Comment: If you're not changing your image, what I thought is not the reason for your error. Sorry, I can't help, I hope someone else will.

Comment: I would contact the SE staff and asking for support or clarification